# How use Apple maps in iOS 9 on objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, ios9

I am using this code for apple maps integration.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D rdOfficeLocation ;

//Apple Maps, using the MKMapItem class

MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:rdOfficeLocation addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *item = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
       // NSLog(@"val is %@",placemark);
        //item.name = @"ReignDesign Office";
[item openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];
```

The above code is put in `viewDidLoad` method its come like this.

But I want user to enter the location in search bar that address is showing then how to fetch the address in `NSLOG`

If we want select the location by using hand gestures how to get that address location and lat,longitude values.

If anyone knows that process please let me know.

[map image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgX1N.jpg)

Comment: You also get address from Google Autocomplete API
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=geocode&language=fr&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: i don't know that process.Please tell me How to do that process?

Comment: I am using apple maps but why to we use google api's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use google place search API for your need.
First you have to get API key from google developer console.
and the use below URL for get search places 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=geocode&language=fr&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Download Library From [Github](https://github.com/spoletto/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete)

Step-1) first add class `@class SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery;` before the `@interface class` in your viewController.h>>>>>>

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery *searchQuery;
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *mutArrSearchData;

@end
```

then your viewDidLoad >>>

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.mutArrSearchData = [NSMutableArray array];

    searchQuery = [[SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery alloc] init];
    self.mutArrSearchData = [NSMutableArray array];

}
```

step-2) then if you are using UISearchBar then set delegate and add Delegate Methods. For EX:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
    textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

    if (searchBar.text.length>=1) {
        [self handleSearchForSearchString:sender.text];
    }
}

- (void)handleSearchForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self.mutArrSearchData removeAllObjects];
    searchQuery.location = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
    searchQuery.input = searchString;
    [searchQuery fetchPlaces:^(NSArray *places, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            SPPresentAlertViewWithErrorAndTitle(error, @"Could not fetch Places");
        } else {

//            you have got your related responce in this array
            [self.mutArrSearchData addObjectsFromArray:places];
            NSLog(@"responce:%@",self.mutArrSearchData);

            //[self.tableview reloadData];
        }
    }];
}
```

you have got responce in up method. now you can parce this responce in your tableview. and didSelect Method....

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    yourCell *aCell;

    [aCell.yourLbl.text setText:[self placeAtIndexPath:indexPath].name];
    return aCell;
}

// Called after the user changes the selection.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SPGooglePlacesAutocompletePlace *place = [self placeAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [place resolveToPlacemark:^(CLPlacemark *placemark, NSString *addressString, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            SPPresentAlertViewWithErrorAndTitle(error, @"Could not map selected Place");
        } else if (placemark) {

            // your selected placemark here. get data from placemark which you needed.

        }
    }];
}

- (SPGooglePlacesAutocompletePlace *)placeAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self.mutArrSearchData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

> make sure to get API_KEY from google developer Console.

Hope it helps you.